# How to create a Installation Bundle Package?

Tags: installation, package, packaging

I have an application which require .net 2 and .net 4 framework with adobe reader , i want to install them before software installation, how i am supposed to do this? Kindly please guide me towards right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done by adding the packages you need as prerequisites for the main installer. Most commercial setup tools support prerequisites one way or another. Here is a list which can get you started:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Pick a tool and try using it to create your installer and add prerequisites for it. I recommend Advanced Installer or InstallShield. If you want a free solution, you can try WiX.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is basically a [suite installation](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html). The link I included shows how to do this with Advanced Installer (Disclaimer: I work on this tool). This is a commercial tool, but it saves you from learning to code Wix/NSIS projects, as it is completely GUI driven, thus you can built your installers without writing any code.

Answer (score 0):

With [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) as your installer, you can refer to the following pages for help with detecting and installing .NET:

- [How to ensure a required version of .NET Framework is installed](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_to_insure_a_required_version_of_.NETFramework_is_installed)
- [How to automatically download and install a particular version of .NET if it is not already installed](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_to_Automatically_download_and_install_a_particular_version_of_.NET_if_it_is_not_already_installed)

Comment: Thank you... Still there i dont need detection just a bundle installer, which start and install all software one by one.